# How to get days and hours from diffForHumans with Carbon?

Tags: php, php-carbon

I want to display how many days and hours to a date using `Carbon`, currently I got the code below.

```
Carbon::parse("2017-03-07 17:46:50")->diffForHumans()
```

It outputs:

> 6 days from now

I want it to output something like this:

> 6 days and 12 hours from now

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the level of details like this:

```php
Carbon::parse("2017-03-07 17:46:50")->diffForHumans(['parts' => 6]);
```

You can use a value from 1 to 6. ([Doc](https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-humandiff))

Answer (score -1):

Sorry I got this question today but here it is

```
$now = Carbon::now();
Carbon::parse("2017-03-07 17:46:50")->diffForHumans($now);
```

I hope it works and may help others.

Comment: any specific reason to downvote this? as far as I knw this solves the problem mentioned

Comment: I did not downvote your question, but it's wrong because the default of diffForHumans() is "now", so you are just posting the same result of the question.
He needs the hours not only the days, but this function only shows hours only if the subtracted day is less than a day old unless you add the 'parts' parameter.